# Usage of zumute

Tags: word-usage, adverb

Reading a children's book, I came across the sentence:

*Julian wird etwas mulmig **zumute**.*

Looking up the meaning of *zumute* on Duden and wiktionary, it seems that it means "feel", i.e. Julian started to feel a bit queasy.  Somehow, I don't think that is the whole sense of it since both sources offers a much bigger explanation.  Also, I would like to know what the overlap is with *sich fühlen* and *spüren*.

Comment: zumute is not often used. It is used to express the mood of a person. In this case the mood is mulmig.

Comment: Imho, *zumute* or *zu Mute* (not sure which spelling is correct in which orthography) is used a lot in literature.

Comment: [**Please do not answer a question in comments.**](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/431/why-should-i-edit-or-answer-rather-than-comment) Comments are meant to ask for clarification or to point to issues but they should not be abused to write a half-answer. Having answers in comments makes any later clean-up extremely cumbersome if impossible. Thank you.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz - you are wrong there. It is a general Stack Exchange policy on comments that existed much longer than this site ([read all about comments here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)) - it is expected from all users to clean-up their obsolete comments by themselves. If they don't do that it is janitorial work for the moderators who may not at all be prepared to read all lengthy comment threads to not miss a possibly valuable comment. Note that we do have a menu to purge all comments on a post in one click to make this easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't be correct. »Zumute« is an adjective, »feel« is a verb. So »zumute« does not mean »feel«.

»Zumute« is something that you can be (»mir *ist* heute nicht nach Scherzen *zumute*) or that you can become (»Mir *wird* ganz seltsam *zumute*). Be aware, that you use dative »mir ist/wird«, not nominative »ich bin/werde«. »Ich bin zumute« and »Ich werde zumute« are wrong. »Mir ist (irgendwie) zumute« and »Mir wird (irgendwie) zumute« are correct.

»Jemandem *ist/wird* nach etwas *zumute*« means »somebody *is/gets in/into the mood* for something«:

> Den jungen Männern war nach einem Kampf zumute.
>   The young men was in the mood for a fight.
>
> Mir wird gerade nach etwas Abwechslung zumute.
>   Actually I get into the mood for some change.

»Jemandem *ist* irgendwie *zumute*« means »somebody *feels* somelike«:

> Dem Lehrer *ist* ganz seltsam *zumute*.
>   The teacher *feels* strange.

Comment: Which part of the question does the first sentence answer? Please elaborate ;)

Comment: @Jan: Is replies to the first sentence of the third paragraph: »Looking up the meaning of zumute on Duden and wiktionary, it seems that it means "feel"«. Please read carefully :)

Comment: What I wanted to imply was that there is so much question, that *Can't be correct* can mean anything at first sight, so it would be good to say *what* can't be correct just for clarity ;)

Comment: @Jan: In all languages you have very often the situation, that a sentence without context makes no sense. This is why I gave you some context. You find it in the 2nd and 3rd sentence of the same paragraph. As I said: Please read carefully. And keep you brain turned on while reading.:)

Answer (score 4):

The is no overlap with **spüren** (similar to *percept* or *sense*), which as a transitive verb would require an object. There is just a small overlap with **fühlen**, which can be used also transitively (then see *spüren*) or reflexively as in

> er fühlte sich schlecht.

While *fühlen* is an up-to-date verb and can be flexibly used, *zumute sein* is dated, seldom used and if so, then just in few combinations (e.g. *ängstlich, feierlich, elend*). It describes a somehwat elusive character (more a mood as Carsten mentioned): You can't refer to exactly, what you are feeling (so a pain in the foot is definitely asking for *fühlen* or *spüren* instead), the feelings are just pulled into a specific direction.