# Kein Subjekt in »Mir wird schlecht«?

Tags: grammar, subject

In [dieser Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/22842/usage-of-zumute) kommt ein Satz mit diesem Aufbau vor:

> <*Dativ-Objekt*> <*eine Form von **sein** oder **werden***> <*Adjektiv*>.

nämlich:

> **Julian wird** etwas mulmig **zumute.**

In diesem Beispiel ist auf den ersten Blick nicht ganz offensichtlich, dass *Julian* im Dativ steht, weil der Dativ von *Julian* gleich lautet wie der Nominativ. (»Das ist *der Julian*. Bitte gib *dem Julian* die Hand!«) Ersetzt man den Namen durch ein Pronomen wird das viel offensichtlicher:

> ***Ihm* wird** etwas mulmig **zumute.**  - richtig
>   ***Er* wird** etwas mulmig **zumute.**  - falsch

Andere Sätze nach diesem Schema sind beispielsweise:

> Dem Jungen ist kalt.
>   Mir wird bange.
>   Der Frau ist schlecht.
>   Ihm wird übel.

Meinem Gefühl nach sind das alles vollständige Sätze, denen nichts fehlt. Ich wüsste jedenfalls nicht, was man da noch zwingend hinzufügen müsste, und diese Sätze zu vervollständigen.

Dennoch hat keiner dieser Sätze ein Subjekt, denn dieses müsste im Nominativ stehen. In diesen Sätzen steht aber genau gar nichts im Nominativ.

Wenn ich mich aber recht erinnere, hat jeder vollständige deutsche Satz genau ein Subjekt und genau ein Prädikat. Alle weitere Elemente eines Satzes sind optional, aber Subjekt und Prädikat muss es immer geben.

Ich habe sogar mal gelesen, dass diese Regel (jeder Satz hat ein Subjekt und ein Prädikat) sogar für alle bekannten Sprachen der Erde gilt, und man diese Regel daher als eine Regel ansieht, die zu einer Universal-Grammatik aller Sprachen gehört.

Oder was ist damit:

> *Mich* friert.
>   *Ihn* dürstet (nach Wasser).

Auch diese Sätze erscheinen mir vollständig zu sein, aber hier gibt es anstelle eines Subjekts ein Akkusativ-Objekt.

Wie passt das alles damit zusammen, dass in einem ganzen Satz das Subjekt immer vorhanden und immer im Nominativ stehen muss? Gibt es Ausnahmen von dieser Regel?

Comment: Related, but not identical: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4701/is-mir-ist-kalt-correct-did-i-hear-it-correctly

Comment: Was mir grad noch einfällt... "jeder deutsche Satz"... das wären dann auch Imperative, und die haben selten ein Subjekt. Könntest du das editieren?

Comment: @Emanuel: Ich kann dir nicht ganz folgen. Was genau meinst du?

Comment: Du sagst "Jeder deutsche Satz hat genau ein Subjekt". "Mach das Fenster zu !" ist ein deutscher Satz und hat kein Subjekt. Deine Frage macht erst Sinn, wenn du Imperative ausklammerst.

Comment: In »Mach das Fenster zu!« steckt das Subjekt gemeinsam mit dem Prädikat im Wort »mach«. Der Satz ist unvollständig, denn er ist eine Verkürzung von »Mach du das Fenster zu!« Das wird noch deutlicher, wenn man in die Höflichkeitsform wechselt: »Machen das Fenster zu!« sagt nieman, weil man das *Sie* in »Machen *Sie* das Fenster zu!« im Gegensatz zum »Du« nicht weglassen kann.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast... warum kann es nicht weggelassen werden? Du kannst doch nicht einfach immer wenn es fehlt, behaupten es wäre "eingebaut" und wenn es nicht fehlt, sagen, es ist nicht eingebaut. Entweder es ist da, oder nicht. Und wenn es nicht da ist, dann funktioniert der Satz auch ohne das Subjekt. Subjekt ist nicht gleich Agens.

Comment: In dieser Magisterarbeit werden Imperativsätze in der 2. Person Singular ebenfalls explizit als subjektlos bezeichnet. Wenn du dieser wissenschaftlichen Definition nicht zustimmst, dann ist das kein Problem, aber dann gibt es keine Disussionsgrundlage. http://www.cis.uni-muenchen.de/download/publikationen/magarb-langer92.pdf

Comment: http://www.verbalissimo.com/main/offers/languages/germanic/german/d_german_no_subject.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Die Regel, dass es immer ein Subjekt gibt, gibt es in der deutschen Sprache nicht. Beispiele sind zum einen die Konstruktionen nach dem Schema "Mir ist.." und zum anderen eine theoretisch hohe Anzahl von subjektlosen Passivsätzen wie diesem:

> Hier wurde gefeiert.

Auch in manch anderen Sprachen gilt diese Regel nicht. In Italienisch zum Beispiel.

> Piove.
> Regnet.
>
> Sono stancho.
> Bin müde.

Was die Regel in Bezug auf "Prädikat" angeht, müsste man zunächst klären, was mit "Prädikat" denn genau gemeint ist. Wenn damit ein Verb gemeint ist (wie man es in der Schule mal gelernt hat), dann gilt diese Regel in vielen Sprachen ebenfalls nicht, die prädikative Adjektive ohne Kopula anschließen.

> Ich müde.

Ergo... die Regeln existieren in der Form nicht.

EDIT:
Ohne das alles im Detail zu verstehen, scheint mir [dieser Artikel](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relationale_Typologie) auf Wikipedia doch klar zu machen, dass das Subjekt nicht in allen Sprachen gleich wichtig ist und teils sogar niederrangiger als das Objekt.

Comment: Ist das nicht bloß ein "Es wird mir schlecht." bei dem das Es umgangssprachlich wegrationalisiert worden ist?

Comment: @MaxRied.. kann auch sein. Ändert aber nix an der Tatsache, dass stadardmäßig keins mehr da ist.

Comment: Das ist wahr, aber das verhindert meiner Ansicht, dass es eine korrekte Regel dafür gibt.

Comment: @MaxRied.. hab' ich doch auch nicht behauptet, oder?

Comment: Ich gebe mich geschlagen. Ich wollte versuchen, Passiv und Imperativ irgendwie schlüssig mit in die Theorie einzubauen, bin aber am Passiv gescheitert. Es waren zu viele Annahmen nötig, die nach Occams Rasiermesser zu einer schlechten Theorie geführt hätten. *Jeder deutsche Deklarativsatz im Aktiv* ist halt doch etwas anderes als *jeder Satz*.

Comment: Das italienische »sono« heißt auch nicht »bin«, sondern »ich bin«. Da steckt das Subjekt gemeinsam mit dem Prädikat in einem Wort. Anderes Beispiel: Latein: »Veni, vidi, vici« heißt auch nicht »gekommen, gesehen, gesiegt», sondern »Ich bin gekommen, ich habe gesehen, ich habe gesiegt« (oft fälschlich zu »Ich kam, sah und siegte« verkürzt). Auch hier steckt das Subjekt mit dem Prädikat gemeinsam im selben Wort. Das Subjekt ist also im Satz vorhanden. Bei »Mir ist schlecht« sehe ich das nicht so.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast... warum ist es denn vorhanden. Wohl doch wegen der Flexion. Sonst wüsste man ja nicht, dass es sich um die erste Person Singular handert. Nun, die Flexion gibt es in Deutsch auch. "Hast einen Hut auf". Informationtheoretisch habe ich alles, was ich brauche. Allerdings würde hier wohl keiner auf die Idee kommen, zu behaupten, der Satz hätte ein Subjekt. Aber warum? Was macht den deutschen Satz anders als den Italienischen? Beide Sätze müssen nach gleichen Kriterien analysiert werden, und entweder haben beide ein Subjekt oder keiner.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ich bleibe bei dem Teil meiner (gelöschten) These, dass das Subjekt in deinen Beispielen da war, aber weggelassen worden ist. Ebenso wie in den italienischen Beispielen. Die Sätze sind ohne Subjekt zwar verkürzt, aber man kann es dazustellen und es fällt nicht auf. Die wahren Probleme sind subjektlose Passivkonstruktionen.

Comment: Davon, dass das Subjekt kein universelles Element jedes vollständigen Satzes jeder Sprache ist, hat mich neben dieser Antwort von Emanuel auch dieser Wikipedia-Artikel überzeugt: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjekt_(Grammatik) und