# The missing subject in "Nun durfte aber im Dienst nicht geraucht werden"

Tags: sentence-structure

The question is on the highlighted bit in this excerpt from Kafka's Der Verschollene.

> **Nun durfte aber im Dienst nicht geraucht werden**, die Folge dessen war, daß im Schlafsaal jeder, solange er nicht unbedingt schlief, auch rauchte.

**Questions**

1. Am I right that it does not have a subject?
2. How strange or not strange is it for the subject to go missing like that?  Can you give an idea of when that is allowed, or perhaps other examples?  The only ones I know are things like:

> Mir ist so wunderbar.

Comment: Related: [Kein Subjekt in »Mir wird schlecht«?](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/22845/9551)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The usual “zero subject” is *es*. It’s necessary to keep the finite verb in second position:

> ***Es** durfte im Dienst nicht geraucht werden.*

If some other word or phrase, e.g. an adverbial, takes its place, *es* can and often must be omitted. This can also happen when the word order is changed:

> ***Es** ist mir so ?wunderbar.*

Answer (score 2):

In German, a subject may be missing for various reasons:

- Some adjectives do not work well with „*ich bin …*“. Instead, you say „*mir ist …*“ („I feel …“):

  > Mir ist schlecht / kalt / langweilig /…
- Giving orders, the subject *Du* is usually omitted (but *Sie* must remain):

  > Höre gut zu! — *normal form without subject*
  >
  > Sei Du bloß still! — *strong, not polite*
  >
  > Kommen Sie herein! — *to strangers*
- The passive form of an intransitive verb may easily lose its anonymous subject *Es*:

  > Wird dir geholfen?
  >
  > Hier wird dir geholfen.
  >
  > Heute wird getanzt und gefeiert.
  >
  > Nun darf gelacht werden.
  >
  > Danach wird gegessen.
  >
  > Wann wird hier geschlossen?
  >
  > Jetzt wird geschlafen!
- Short phrases often drop the subject due to an ellipsis:

  > Nein, danke.
  >
  > Wie bitte?
  >
  > Macht nichts.